# Mysql concat severals rows

Tags: mysql, multiple-columns, rows, concatenation

Using `Mysql` and I am trying to concatenate several rows by using `CONCAT_WS` but I didn't get the desired output.

My table `testtable` has the following structure:

```
vardel1 int(50)
vardel2 int(50)
ComputeVariant varchar(50)

+----------+-------------------+----------------+
| vardel1d | vardel2           | ComputeVariant |
+----------+-------------------+----------------+
|  167     | 181               |  NULL          |
+----------+-------------------+----------------+
```

with my `testtable` I'm doing a join with another table (`posnucleo`) to compute values, `2235` and `2249`.

My desired output is in `ComputeVariant` column is:

```
c.2235_2249del
```

My sql query is the following:

```
update testtable, posnucleo
   set testtable.ComputeVariant = CONCAT_WS( CONCAT('c.', abs(((posnucleo.1stpos - posnucleo.1stnuclocode) - testtable.vardel1 )) ), CONCAT('_',abs(((posnucleo.1stpos - posnucleo.1stnuclocode) - testtable.vardel2 )),'del' ) )
 where testtable.Reference = posnucleo.amplicon
```

My issue is that I don't have the desired output. I also try to concat with `||` but it seems not working too. `GROUP_CONCAT` doesn't work either.

Do you have any idea how to resolve my issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your query would be easier to read with explicit `join` syntax and table aliases.

I think you are overcomplicated the string concatenation.  You can pass multiple arguments to `concat()`, like this:

```
update testtable tt join
       posnucleo pn
       on tt.Reference = pn.amplicon
    set tt.ComputeVariant = CONCAT('c.',
                                   abs((pn.1stpos - pn.1stnuclocode) - tt.vardel1 ) ),
                                   '_',
                                   abs((pn.1stpos - pn.1stnuclocode) - tt.vardel2 ),
                                   'del'
                                  );
```